# C# - Windows Form Chart - AxisX.IntervalOffset doesn't work

Tags: c#, charts, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to offset my majorGrids and LabelStyle. When I set an interval it works fine, but when I try to offset that interval I can't get it to work.

The data being graphed has fixed points along the x-axis. They are always the same and logarithmic (not sure if relevant).

No matter what the value of IntervalOffset I've tried it's always the same. I've tried setting the IntervalOffsetType and Interval type as well (different things I've tried shown in code). What I would like is the labels and majorGridLines to start at 63 and repeat for every three points.

Here is some code:

**Code in form which contains chart**

```
private void setupChart()
{
    // Setup Chart
    chartPathData.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;


    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = 1;
    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 3;
    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = 0;
    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalOffsetType = 0;

    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 1;
    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 3;
    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
     chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;


    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
}

private void GraphPath(Pathdata pathData, string pathName, Color color)
{
    var seriesPath = new Series
    {
        Name = pathName,
        IsVisibleInLegend = true,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        Color = color,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine
    };

    chartPathData.Series.Add(seriesPath);

    // GraphPath just creates a graphable version
    // of pathData assigning X values at the corresponding
    // properties (creating x,y points)
    GraphPath graphPath = new GraphPath(pathData);
    foreach (GraphPoint point in graphPath.GraphPoints)
    {               
        seriesPath.Points.AddXY(point.x, point.y);
    }

}
```

**DataPath Class**

```
    public class DataPath
{        
    public ThirdOctaveValue A50 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A63 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A80 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A100 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A125 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A160 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A200 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A250 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A315 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A400 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A500 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A630 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A800 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A1000 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A1250 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A1600 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A2000 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A2500 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A3150 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A4000 { get; set; }
    public ThirdOctaveValue A5000 { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is the result**

[image]

Comment: I think you overriding `chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = 0;` with `chartPathData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;`

Comment: What you want is __maybe__ not supported for [`FastLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489249.aspx). - Try   `ChartType.Line` instead

Comment: @RomanSidorov - those are just examples of what I have tried. That isn't necessarily the only combination I tried using. I meant for the bottom Interval type to pertain to the major grid to show that both values do not work.

Comment: @TaW - this doesn't work either.

Comment: Hm, is 63 one of your x-values? Also : The code as posted seems a little confused: Setting types to `0` means Auto but is hard to understand. And as Roman noted you are setting LabelStyle.IntervalType twice. Remove all typos etc and see what happens. I think all works fine is you have clean code..

Comment: Ok, I fixed the type for overwriting the value of IntervalType and IntervalTypeOffset. If you look at the class for the data, 63 is indeed one of the values. I've tried the code you see above in addition to leaving IntervalType and IntervalTypeOffset to their default values and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have a feeling IntervalOffset isn't connected to anything. I'm able to reproduce your issues, and in .net 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the `Axis.IntervalOffset()` property has no effect. Studying the [public .net source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.DataVisualization/Common/General/Axis.cs,daee9584f510dbde) shows this, the parameter is not referenced anywhere other than its own assignment and retrieval.

Any solution that sets the `IntervalOffset` using the `Minimum` and the `Interval` parameters implicitly sets the zero point of the axis, without ever needing to set the parameter. However this can only be done once autocalculation of the minimum has been done internally by the `Axis`. Once the Minimum has been manually set once, auto-calculation is disengaged, and manual recalculation is required. Addition or removal of data requires the following, assuming the chart in question is `Chart1`, the `ChartArea` is of index zero, the axis of interest is `AxisX`, and the axis' .Interval has been set to a nonzero value.:

```
With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
    .AxisX.Minimum = Double.NaN
    .Recalculate()
    .AxisX.Minimum = .AxisX.Interval * System.Math.Floor(.AxisX.Minimum / .AxisX.Interval)
End With
```

The first line resets the `Minimum` to the non-fixed value (Double.NaN); the second line forces the axis to recalculate its exact bounds based on the data displayed; the third sets the `Minimum` equal to an integer multiple of the interval, to the left of (or numerically below) the exact minimum of the data.

In so doing, the axis is spaced on the specified interval, in whole multiples of the interval, beyond the limits of the data. Strictly, this does not set the maximum value, which is allowed to float to the exact maximum of the data, so the following can be done for completeness:

```
With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
    .AxisX.Minimum = Double.NaN
    .AxisX.Maximum = Double.NaN
    .Recalculate()
    .AxisX.Minimum = .AxisX.Interval * System.Math.Floor(.AxisX.Minimum / .AxisX.Interval)
    .AxisX.Maximum = .AxisX.Interval * System.Math.Ceiling(.AxisX.Maximum / .AxisX.Interval)
End With
```

This sets both ends, and the axis now behaves like the Y axis natively behaves with data.